# Once again including library and Error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, zbar, lnk2001

I have a problem with Visual Studio 2013 and Error LNK2001.
I tried to linking Zbar Library - I have downloaded, instaled and linked this library

I tried to run this simple program:

```
#include "zbar.h"  

using namespace zbar;
int main()

{
  ImageScanner scanner;
  return 0;
}
```

I can compile this, but can't build it.
I can see this:

> Error 1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol zbar_image_scanner_destroy    C:\Users\n\Documents\nn\ZBar_detektor\Opencv_projekt\main.obj   Opencv_projekt
>
> Error 2   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol zbar_image_scanner_create C:\Users\n\Documents\nn\ZBar_detektor\Opencv_projekt\main.obj   Opencv_projekt

I know that except *include* directory, I have to link *lib* files

I did it this way:
[image]

Except that, I copy everything from */bin* directory, and paste it to */Windows/System*

In some cases, in the past this operation helped, but not this time - still can see Error LNK2001

Any clues or advices? Help please

Best regards, Fidor

Comment: Does zbar include a sample Visual Studio project?  Look at it to see what lib files you are missing.

Comment: Go to VC++ directories and add the path where the binary file is located

Comment: Otherwise, just make sure zbar.lib is in all these directories: `/src` and `bin/release` and `bin/debug`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general: Thanks you! Zbar include sample VS project, but it required strange additional libraries. But that gave me a solution: Problem was, that my project was x64, and zbar are x32, and need kernel32.dll. When I changed my project configuration ewerything started work